# populate checkboxes and then update selection to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a form where checkboxes are populated from a MySQL database using:

```
//possible array values in row(value)
$values = array('F', 'R', 'C', 'T', 'S');
// $names =  array('football', 'rugby', 'cricket', 'tennis', 'swimming')
$sql = "SELECT value, description
    FROM table_1
    WHERE ID = '$userid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$db_values[] = $row['0'];
```

Then the checkboxes are pre-selected using:

```
<?php
foreach ($values as $value) {
$selected = in_array($value, $db_values) ? ' checked="checked"' : null;
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sports[]' id ='sport' value=" . $value . $selected . "/>" . $value . "<br />";
} ?>
```

This part is working okay and gives an output of:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='sports[]' id ='sport' value='F' checked='checked'/>F
```

Part 1: I am trying to edit it further though in order to display the name beside the checkbox instead of the value like such:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='sports[]' id ='sport' value='F' checked='checked'/>football
```

Anyone any ideas on this?

Part 2: I am now trying to update whatever checkboxes are checked/de-checked and update the values into the same database table. 
I have tried:

```
$sports = $_POST["sports"];
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($sports); $i++) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table_1
            SET value='$sports[$i], ID='$userid'
            WHERE ID='$userid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

But I am probably going about this part completely the wrong way but I cant figure out how to get it to work.

I keep getting error:

```
Duplicate entry 'ID-value' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

For every choice I submit

Thanks, in advance for any help.

EDIT..............................

Table_1 like this

```
ID   |  Sport
John |  F
John |  C
John |  R
Paul |  R
```

The problem arises if I leave a checkbox ticked and then click update.
If the user has no entries and I check the box it seems to update fine
A combination of ID-Sport is the Primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not same id more that once in a page.

And enclose value attribute with `'`

```
<?php
   foreach ($values as $value) {
   $selected = in_array($value, $db_values) ? ' checked="checked"' : null;
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sports[]' id ='sport' value='" . $value ."' " . $selected . "/>" . $value . "<br />";
} ?>
```

Create array like this

```
$arr['F'] = "Football";
$arr['R'] = "Rugby";
$arr['C'] = "Cricket";

$arr[$value] instead of $value
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
    $arr['F'] = "Football";
    $arr['R'] = "Rugby";
    $arr['C'] = "Cricket";
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $selected = in_array($value, $db_values) ? ' checked="checked"' : null;
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sports[]' id ='sport' value=" . $value . $selected . "/>" . $arr[$value] . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Any help on any of my questions though?

Comment: didnt get what exactly ur telling

Comment: OK for part 1 I want it to output as **<input type='checkbox' name='sports[]' id ='sport' value='F' checked='checked'/>football** instead of what it is currently showing **<input type='checkbox' name='sports[]' id ='sport' value='F' checked='checked'/>F**

Comment: what is the value for `$values`?

Comment: '$values' is an array with the follwoing entries ('F', 'R', 'C', 'T', 'S');

Comment: Is F always equa. To football??

Comment: Yes, F is always football, R is always rugby, C is always cricket, etc.

Comment: Hi Niranjan, I'm not following your suggestion. So where should I create this array? What should this replace? How will this output to the checkbox? I am a bit lost with this at the minute

Comment: Thanks Niranjan, it is working perfectly. Exactly the way I want it to. Any chance you would be able to help me with Part 2 of my question?

Comment: change query like this, `$sql = "UPDATE table_1  SET value='$sports[$i]  WHERE ID='$userid'";`

Comment: I am still getting the duplicate error - " Duplicate entry 'MEMBER-C' for key 'PRIMARY' ". (where MEMBER is the userID and C is the entry for cricket). For example if a user already has entries in the table for all 5 sports then when I try and uncheck F for example and submit i get the duplicate error. I will EDIT my post above to explain